# Riemannian manifold, $\alpha \in \Omega^p(M)$ parallel implies $\alpha$ is closed?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold, and let $\alpha \in \Omega^p(M)$ be parallel; i.e. suppose $\nabla \alpha = 0$ where $\nabla$ is the Levi-Civita connection. Does it necessarily follow that $\alpha$ is closed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes I believe so. We have the formula that $$(p+1)\nabla_{[a}\alpha_{b\dots c]}=(d\alpha)_{ab\dots c}\in \Omega^{p+1}(M)$$This is in [abstract index notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_index_notation). So $\nabla\alpha=0$ implies the antisymmetric part is also $0$, so $d\alpha=0$

Comment: what does mean $\nabla \alpha$ ??? does it mean $\nabla_\alpha \alpha= 0$ ? or $\nabla_{\partial x_i} \alpha = 0$ for every $i$ ?

Comment: It is a particular section of the $p+1$ tensor product of the cotangent bundle. In any coordinate system, yes, it means that $\nabla_{\partial x_i}\alpha=0$. See here: https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/March01/Carroll3/Carroll3.html

Comment: it is $\nabla_u a = 0$ for some given smooth vector field $u$ ?

Comment: For any vector field $u$, yes.

Comment: ok the operator $u \to \nabla_u a$ is the $u \to 0$ operator

Comment: Yes, as a map from $\Gamma (M,TM)\to \Gamma (M,\bigotimes^{p+1}T^{\ast}M)$, $u\mapsto \nabla_u\alpha$ is the map $u\mapsto 0$.